# php preg_match find a word i a string

Tags: php, preg-match

i have a database with more than 20.000 posts on it. most of the posts have a signature:

like this one :

```
If in my dreams is the only
place i can hould u !

Then i want to sleep forever !!

Me:bb:272F9F64
```

so i want to print all the posts insde my database who contain signatures like (Me:PIN:272F9F64 )

all those signatures are starting with ( PIN: or PIN ) and they are 8 digits numbers and alphabit.

i used this code to print them but it is not working

```
$get_tit = $db->query("select id,name from brd limit 1000");
while($th=$db->fetch($get_tit)){

 if (preg_match("/PIN:[0-9a-zA-Z]+/", $th['name'])) {
    echo $th['name']."<br>";
    }
}
```

UPDATED ******

this code for loop throw the database and delete any signature inside the post

```
$get_tit = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM brd LIMIT 1000");
echo 'Results Found :'.mysql_num_rows($get_tit).'<br /><br />';
while($th=$db->fetch($get_tit)){
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE brd SET name=LEFT(name,LENGTH(name)-12) WHERE name REGEXP 'PIN:[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}$' and id='$th[id]'") or die(mysql_error());      

}
```

but it is not working the signature still there

any help Guys

Bbway

Comment: If these are Blackberry messenger PINS: 1) it's probably not a smart idea to put what seems to be a real PIN in your question. 2) The codes are made of hex characters, so instead of `a-zA-Z`, you just need `a-fA-F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done really easily within MySQL:

```
SELECT id, name FROM brd WHERE name REGEXP 'PIN:[0-9a-zA-Z]+$' LIMIT 1000
```

Are you sure `name` is the field that has the post in it, though? I don't know how you have your database designed, but personally I'd have `name` as the name of the user, and `content` as the content of the post. Make sure you have the right field name.

Comment: yes it works .... so now how can i update the database after deleting the signature

Comment: If you don't have `REGEX_REPLACE` available as a user-defined function, you could try something dirtier since you know how long the signature is: `UPDATE brd SET name=LEFT(name,LENGTH(name)-12) WHERE name REGEXP 'PIN:[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}$'` - this works because the signature is twelve characters long, according to your question. Just run it once and it's all done.

Comment: As I said, just run the `UPDATE` I gave you ***once*** (ie. through phpMyAdmin or similar), and it'll delete all signatures for you.

Comment: what about if i want to replace it with my own code (PIN:12312312)

Comment: `... SET name=CONCAT(LEFT(name,LENGTH(name)-12),"PIN:12312312") ...` instead of the current `SET` part.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. At this point the best thing to do in my opinion would be to export the database to a file on your computer, and remove the excess PINs with a text editor. Notepad++ has a good Search-and-Replace feature that includes Regex capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id, name, FROM brd WHERE name REGEXP 'PIN:?[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}$' LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add m modifier to your preg match. It's turn on multiline mode.